# I lost my Andriod, can i recover the data from my Google account?

Tags: google-account, data-recovery, remote-control

I have lost my Android device. Is it possible for me to recover the data in the phone using my Google account?

Comment: Not if you haven't backed up when you still had it.

Comment: Which data? Not all data is stored by Google, especially if it is 3rd-party apps.

Answer (score 0):

If you had your phone settings set so they back up your stuff. For examples, settings, Google Photos,etc. Then it's highly likely that it would. Plus something Google have been doing for a while is noting the apps you have installed and give you the option to redownload them when you do a fresh install onto a new device, or a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can recover your data. It just depends on what you want.

- If you're looking **to recover your photos, go to [Google Photos](http://photos.google.com)**, log in, and check to see if your photos are backed up. You can download your photos from here or keep them in Google Photos and restore them from the cloud when you get a new Android phone.
- If you're concerned about your apps, **the Google Play store should remember the apps you had installed** (unless if they weren't downloaded on the Play Store), and you should be given the option to reinstall your apps for free on another phone. As for the data on third-party apps, it will likely depend on the developer.
- If you want anything else on your Google Account, go to [Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout).